# How do different icon/logo techniques work on websites?

Tags: html, css, image, graphics, web

This is mainly a question about the quality of logos/icons used in Websites. I create **logos/icons** using Illustrator but when I see icons on professional websites (see image and links), they look crisp like a text, with no blurriness. The edges are very clear. For example, please see this image, especially the search icon and the menu list icon:

[image]

1. This is my own [Blog](http://vkcreativework.blogspot.in/p/home.html) that has bad icons, the **Logo** and the **Menu icon**. Both of them are **PNG** images.
2. This is [Entrepreneur](https://www.entrepreneur.com/magazine) website with awesome **menu icon** and **search** icon. If you check the **Inspect Element for mobile** site, you'll see that the search icon and menu icon are not images (I don't know actually the reality). It is using a **pseudo** element. How does it work? Maybe this has something to do with quality.
3. Same is true with [TimeofIndia](http://blogs.timesofindia.indiatimes.com/) website. Here the menu icon is made using **hr** tag, so it's obviously great, but still the **search icon** is beyond understanding as it is using a **pseudo** element.
4. And another scenario is related to this [Business Insider](http://www.businessinsider.in/) website's technique. I've seen it at most of the websites, especially Facebook like sites. They use a single image for all icons. How's it possible? If you don't understand please visit this website and check the **URL** of the menu and search icon's image. How's it done?

So first I would like to know how these things work? How these icons render?

Secondly why I'm not getting the quality like them? Should I stop using images like them? I'm asking this because I've tried exporting in many ways using Illustrator, with same dimensions as required, but still quality sucks. If you can see, in my own blog's ([Blog](http://vkcreativework.blogspot.in/p/home.html)) mobile site, the middle horizontal bar is blurred despite the original image looks awesome before upload. Why is that?

I think these are too many questions. I would appreciate if you can provide suitable links to understand these things fully, if explaining them here is not easy.

Thank you.

Comment: They're web pages. You have the full html/css/images/js necessary to render them already downloaded to your computer merely by having visited the site. fire up your dom inspector and start digging.

Comment: They are using SVG icons, that are similar to vector images

Comment: Don't you get good quality using SVG graphics? Set in css as background for example?

Comment: SVG icons can look noticeably better than png or jpg. My last workplace switched its logo to svg and there was a distinct improvement in sharpness. The original logo was designed by our graphic design team so it wasn't that amateurs created the image logo

Comment: @andreaem they *are* vector images (svg = scalable vector graphics) :)

Comment: Does that pseudo element with content '\f400' means vector (svg) image, for search icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I could, I'd give @marc-b five upvotes :) The first step, before coming to SO, should always be trying to solve the problem yourself. Then you can come to us with an [on-topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Here, that first step is to right click on one of the icons you're interested in, and choose "inspect".

There are a couple questions here: what are some ways of making crisp images?, and what's the deal with having multiple images in one file? Both of those are very Googlable, but I'll give you a head start:

Two common ways to make images crisp are:

- SVG (vector graphics - as an Illustrator user you already know about the difference between those and raster graphics, and why they're crisp. If not, google "vector raster difference")
- 2x images - the technique here is to make an image twice the final display size, and then use CSS to shrink it down. The in-browser scaling will have a crisper result that just displaying a 1x image.
- Having more than one image in one is called a "sprite." You can have a raster sprite or an svg sprite.

Here's an intro to svg https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/, here's an intro to sprites https://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/, here's an intro to svg sprites https://css-tricks.com/svg-sprites-use-better-icon-fonts/, and here's an intro to the latest thing, `srcset` https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/

Comment: I did search online but still facing problems. I came to know that search icons and menu bars are created using Font Icons. So I read about it. Now could you please answer this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39674241/what-is-the-difference-between-f400-and-xf042-formats

Comment: The field is generally moving away from icon fonts, in favor of svg's. There are many articles about this, and about icon fonts. For example https://sarasoueidan.com/blog/icon-fonts-to-svg/. I recommend taking an online course or reading through w3schools / css-tricks / etc - questions about fundamentals of front end development aren't really [the kind of question SO is for](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Ok I got it. I've used the menu bar using Font Icons and it's awesome. But now I have problem with using SVG. I entreat you to answer this question if possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39678361/why-isnt-svg-and-text-rendering-on-mobile-browsers?noredirect=1#comment66657693_39678361 Thank you.