# Why isn't SVG and Text rendering on Windows Phone browsers?

Tags: html, css, svg, blogger

The problem is with my blog [My Blog](http://vkcreativework.blogspot.com) If you open it on desktop browser, the Logo **SVG Icon** and Text **PORTFOLIO** render fine, as I want. But when I open this blog on any Mobile browser, neither SVG nor PORTFOLIO are displayed.

Screenshots of Mobile site opened in different Mobile browsers of **Windows Phone**:

1. UC Browser

[image: UC Browser]

2. Google Search (An app by Google Inc.)

[image]

3. Explorer

[image]

It might be possible that Mobile browsers don't support SVG but why isn't PORTFOLIO being displayed?

Is it possible that SVG code has markup mistakes? I just saved it from Illustrator.

Here's the code (please do Inspect Element on My blog to get more details):

```
 <div class='titlewrapper'><div id='titleimage'><a href='http://vkcreativework.blogspot.com'>
    <svg style='enable-background:new 0 0 376.8 442;' version='1.1' viewBox='0 0 376.8 442' x='0px' xml:space='preserve' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' y='0px'>
        <style type='text/css'>
            .st0{display:none;fill:#00A99D;}
            .st1{enable-background:new    ;}
            .st2{fill:#2A2A2A;}
            .st3{clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);enable-background:new    ;}
            .st4{fill:#313131;}
            .st5{fill:#FEFEFE;}
            .st6{clip-path:url(#SVGID_4_);enable-background:new    ;}
        </style>
        <g id='Layer_2'>
            <rect class='st0' height='563' width='654' x='-126.8' y='-42'/>
        </g>
        <g id='Layer_4'>
            <g>
                <g>
                    <g>
                        <g class='st1'>
                            <g>
                                <rect class='st2' height='152.7' transform='matrix(-0.7069 -0.7073 0.7073 -0.7069 -40.7001 753.0775)' width='2.5' x='134.5' y='308.6'/>
                            </g>
                            <g>
                                <rect class='st2' height='101.8' transform='matrix(-0.7069 -0.7073 0.7073 -0.7069 284.2971 923.7317)' width='2.5' x='332.3' y='352'/>
                            </g>
                            <g class='st1'>
                                <defs>
                                    <path class='st1' d='M261.9,259.2l1.7,1.7c27.4,27.4,102,102.2,106.8,106.9l-1.7-1.7         C363.9,361.3,289.3,286.6,261.9,259.2z' id='SVGID_1_'/>
                                </defs>
                                <clipPath id='SVGID_2_'>
                                    <use style='overflow:visible;' xlink:href='#SVGID_1_'/>
                                </clipPath>
                                <g class='st3'>
                                    <path class='st4' d='M261.9,259.2l1.7,1.7c27.4,27.4,102,102.2,106.8,106.9l-1.7-1.7C363.9,361.3,289.3,286.6,261.9,259.2'/>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <g>
                                <path class='st5' d='M226.7,237.1c4.6,0,8.8,1,13.2,3.1c4.4,2.1,8.3,5.8,12.1,9c0.3,0.3,111,111.1,116.8,116.9l-72,72        L188.8,330.1L80.8,438.1l-36.9-36.9l136.5-135.8c8.5-8.5,17.4-16,27.4-22.6c4.6-3,9.8-5,15.4-5.5        C224.4,237.1,225.5,237.1,226.7,237.1z'/>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
                <g>
                    <g>
                        <g class='st1'>
                            <g>
                                <polygon class='st2' points='78.6,6.2 80.3,8 80.1,223.9 78.3,222.1       '/>
                            </g>
                            <g>
                                <polygon class='st2' points='155.4,219.4 157.1,221.1 9.9,367.8 8.2,366       '/>
                            </g>
                            <g class='st1'>
                                <defs>
                                    <path class='st1' d='M257.5,190.3l1.7,1.7c-4.1-1.7-7.8-3.1-11.6-4.2c-7.1-2.1-14.4-3.1-21.8-3.1         c-3.4,0-6.7,0.2-10,0.6c-10.8,1.4-21.2,5-30.5,10.7c-8.3,5-15.2,11.8-22,18.7c-2.1,2.1-4.1,4.2-6.2,6.3l-1.7-1.7         c2.1-2.1,4.1-4.2,6.2-6.3c6.8-6.9,13.8-13.7,22-18.7c9.3-5.6,19.7-9.3,30.5-10.7c3.3-0.4,6.7-0.6,10-0.6         c7.4,0,14.7,1,21.8,3.1C249.7,187.2,253.4,188.6,257.5,190.3z' id='SVGID_3_'/>
                                </defs>
                                <clipPath id='SVGID_4_'>
                                    <use style='overflow:visible;' xlink:href='#SVGID_3_'/>
                                </clipPath>
                                <g class='st6'>
                                    <path class='st4' d='M257.5,190.3l1.7,1.7c-4.1-1.7-7.8-3.1-11.6-4.2c-7.1-2.1-14.4-3.1-21.8-3.1c-3.4,0-6.7,0.2-10,0.6         c-10.8,1.4-21.2,5-30.5,10.7c-8.3,5-15.2,11.8-22,18.7c-2.1,2.1-4.1,4.2-6.2,6.3l-1.7-1.7c2.1-2.1,4.1-4.2,6.2-6.3         c6.8-6.9,13.8-13.7,22-18.7c9.3-5.6,19.7-9.3,30.5-10.7c3.3-0.4,6.7-0.6,10-0.6c7.4,0,14.7,1,21.8,3.1         C249.7,187.2,253.4,188.6,257.5,190.3'/>
                                </g>
                            </g>
                            <g>
                                <polygon class='st2' points='368.7,78.2 370.5,79.9 259.2,192 257.5,190.3       '/>
                            </g>
                            <g>
                                <path class='st5' d='M296,6.2l72.8,72L257.5,190.3c-4.1-1.7-7.8-3.1-11.6-4.2c-7.1-2.1-14.4-3.1-21.8-3.1        c-3.4,0-6.7,0.2-10,0.6c-10.8,1.4-21.2,5-30.5,10.7c-8.3,5-15.2,11.8-22,18.7c-2.1,2.1-4.1,4.2-6.2,6.3L8.2,366L7.6,78.2        l71-72l-0.3,215.9L296,6.2z'/>
                            </g>
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <span id='titletext'>PORTFOLIO</span></a>
 </div>
```

Comment: It's working fine with me, give my screenshot from you mobile, please.

Comment: I checked with Opera Mobile browser. It's fine. So the problem is with Internet Explorer, UC Browser and one Google's application named Google Search, which is similar to Chrome. I've added the screenshots in details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that for your SVG logo, you have only specified a width.  IE has scaling issues if you don't specify both a width and a height.  So try adding a value for `height` and see if that makes a difference.

I don't know much about the UC Browser.  I couldn't find any definitive information on whether it supports SVG or not. One page I found said it didn't and another said it did.  I don't know what engine it uses on WP either. If it uses the IE engine, then it could be affected by the same issue.

Comment: Ok, but why the PORTFOLIO text is not rendered along with SVG? What is the connection? Did you notice?

Comment: I don't have an explanation for that. My guess is probably wrong. But I thought it worth mentioning as something to try.

Comment: Wow! It works now in all mobile browsers and even Internet Explorer! Thank you. And now I have found out something for that PORTFOLIO confusion. Actually it was rendering always but was not visible as the default height I saw in an example I tried was somewhat 100px, that's why the PORTFOLIO Text went below the Fixed element and having z-index low it wasn't visible. Now could you please tell if I should add this line above my SVG code or not? It was there when I saved it from Illustrator. Without it it's still working. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

Comment: Ah yes of course. That does make sense. I am glad that worked. As for the XML declaration line: no. You do not need it and should not include it with inlined SVG.

Comment: Ok but why Illustrator mentions it then? Also I think I need to read about <svg> tag. I don't know anything about it, I just used it. There are many things between this tag, like Fill, <g> tags, Width, Height, x, y. Where can I read about it?